# How to read a .txt file json into dictionary in swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

hi i have one json in following structure

```
{
  "SCALE085": {
    "Fingerprints": [
      {
        "FingerImpressionImage": {
          "BinaryBase64ObjectBMP": "aaaaaaaaaa"
        }
      },
       {
        "FingerImpressionImage": {
          "BinaryBase64ObjectBMP": "bbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      },
     {
        "FingerImpressionImage": {
          "BinaryBase64ObjectBMP": "cccccccccc"
        }
      },
       {
        "FingerImpressionImage": {
          "BinaryBase64ObjectBMP": "dddddddddd"
        }
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

my json saved in this location

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4D2740FA-B119-46EB-8EDD-5FEFA11CFEC1/Documents/TEstApp/ExportDemo/swift_fingerprints_0_2020.03.02_01.06.10.txt
```

and what am trying to achieve is get the values of key "BinaryBase64ObjectBMP" in an array like below

["aaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbb","cccccccccc","dddddddddd"]

how do i do this?

i have passed full file path into below function but it got crashed

```
 func readFromFile(file:URL){
        let url = file
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [[[String: Any]]]
            print(json)

        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

the crash was saying no such files

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4D2740FA-B119-46EB-8EDD-5FEFA11CFEC1/Documents/TEstApp/ExportDemo/swift_fingerprints_0_2020.03.02_01.06.10.txt
```

but i can see the file in folder also

Comment: You have to get the URL to the documents folder from `FileManager` every time you want to access it and the JSON is clearly `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access document folder first then append your file name and check if file exist on that path like below..

```
func getFileDocumentDirectory(name: String) -> URL? {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            return fileURL
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

In your case the file name would be "swift_fingerprints_0_2020.03.02_01.06.10.txt".